# jQuery select class but not certain data attributes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to select a number of div elements of a certain class but not having certain data attributes. For example, I have 12 divs with data attributes from 1 to 12 and I want to select all of them except those with data attribute 1, 11 and 12. This is my (not working) code so far:

```
$('div.randomize_class [data-value!=1],[data-value!=11],[data-value!=12]');
```

The aim is to shuffle only the matched divs and eventually append the ones with attribute 1, 11 and 12 at the end. The shuffling function works nicely, it's only about selecting a subset of the select class.

So after shuffling, I want to select only those with data attributes 1, 11 and 12. I tried this:

```
$('.randomize_class [data-value=1],[data-value=11],[data-value=12]')
```

Would be glad for any help! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in combination with attribute value selector.

*to select only those with data attributes 1, 11 and 12*

```
$('.randomize_class').filter('[data-value=1],[data-value=11],[data-value=12]')
```

*to select all of them except those with data attribute 1, 11 and 12.* [:not() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) or [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function to exclude the elements

```
 $('.randomize_class').filter(':not([data-value=1]),:not([data-value=11]),:not([data-value=12])')
```

OR

```
$('div.randomize_class').not('[data-value=1],[data-value=11],[data-value=12]');
```

Answer (score 6):

You've said you both want to *not* select the `data-value=1` (and 11 and 12), and also that you *do* want to.

---

For the *not* case, you can use [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('div.randomize_class:not([data-value=1]):not([data-value=11]):not([data-value=12])');
```

...which has the advantage of also working in CSS (not that I think that really applies here), provided you only use [*simple selectors*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors) inside `:not` (as CSS defines `:not` only takes simple selectors; jQuery goes further).

Or its cousin [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) (which the `:not` documentation suggests is usually a better option):

```
$('div.randomize_class').not('[data-value=1], [data-value=11], [data-value=12])');
```

---

For the option of selecting *only* the `data-value=1` (and 11 and 12), you do it with a simple attribute selector series:

```
$('div.randomize_class[data-value=1], div.randomize_class[data-value=11], div.randomize_class[data-value=12])');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not) to exclude those items

```
$('div.randomize_class').not('[data-value!=1],[data-value!=11],[data-value!=12]');
```

Your selector `.randomize_class [data-value=1],[data-value=11],[data-value=12]` will fetch all elements under `randomize_class` with `data-value=1` and all elements in the page with `data-value=11` or `data-value=12`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.randomize_class:not([data-value="1"],[data-value="11"],[data-value="12"])')
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to complement it with context, detailed information and/or code examples. The _Post Answer_ button should be used only for **complete answers to the question**.